# ClamAV-Test-File virus definition

Tags: clamav

Today I scanned my machine with ClamAV, and this was one of the things that it detected:

```
/home/<username>/clamav-devel/contrib/test/clam_cache_emax.tgz
```

And it detected it as:

```
ClamAV-Test-File
```

So what exactly is this `ClamAV-Test-File` definition? I have not seen it come up before.

OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

Package Information:

```
clamav:
  Installed: 0.98.6+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.10.1
  Candidate: 0.98.6+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.10.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.98.6+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.10.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.98.4+dfsg-2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ClamAV-Test-File` file is like an [EICAR](http://www.eicar.org/56-0-Home.html) file: it's used to test the behaviour of your anti-virus solution.

These kinds of files offer you the possibility to simulate a virus infection without actually infecting your system as they only contain the **signature** of a virus.